# Error while installing GeoPandas using pipenv "proj executable not found"

Tags: python, geopandas, proj

I tried to install GeoPandas using the following command:

> pipenv install geopandas

But I had an error:

```
Installing geopandas…
Error:  An error occurred while installing geopandas!
Error text: Collecting geopandas
Using cached geopandas-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (994 kB)
Collecting pyproj>=2.2.0
Using cached pyproj-3.0.1.tar.gz (168 kB)
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\mm\.virtualenvs\Python_Scripts-6r4YuOo9\Scripts\python.exe'
```

'C:\Users\mm.virtualenvs\Python_Scripts-6r4YuOo9\lib\site-
packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel
'C:\Users\mm\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpojq98inx'
cwd: C:\Users\mm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xw_50bxm\pyproj
Complete output (1 lines):
proj executable not found. Please set the PROJ_DIR variable. For more information see:
https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/installation.html
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\mm.virtualenvs\Python_Scripts-
6r4YuOo9\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\mm.virtualenvs\Python_Scripts-6r4YuOo9\lib\site-
packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel
'C:\Users\mm\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpojq98inx' Check the logs for full command output.

```
    Installation Failed
```

What should I do?

Comment: You have instructions directly in that error message. `proj executable not found. Please set the PROJ_DIR variable. For more information see: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/installation.html`

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I did it with conda. No error happened with Conda.